# How change tables's schema of Identity Server 4?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

By default the  tables's schema of Identity Server 4 is `dbo`, i want change it to security, so i create `ConfigurationContext` which inherit from `ConfigurationDbContext`:

```cs
 public class ConfigurationContext : ConfigurationDbContext
 {
    public ConfigurationContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions) : base(options, storeOptions)
    { }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Security");
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var relationalOptions = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(optionsBuilder.Options);
        relationalOptions.MigrationsHistoryTableSchema = "Security";
    }

  }
```

and in `add-migration` i use `ConfigurationContext` :

```
Add-Migration -c ConfigurationContext
```

but i got this error:

> No parameterless constructor was found on 'ConfigurationContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'ConfigurationContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'ConfigurationContext'.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

IdentityServer4 provides this option. In `ConfigureServices`,

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddOperationalStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(cnStr, options =>
                        options.MigrationsAssembly(migAssembly)),
                        storeOption => storeOption.DefaultSchema = "security")
```

This way, you can continue to use the `IDbContextFactory` as suggested in the quickstarts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I did the change on top of the sample QuickStart for EF from here - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage. However when run it still creates tables in dbo schema instead. Are there any other steps involved?

Comment: This will not work, migrations will still be executed on the dbo schema.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite an old question, but I recently had a similar issue; June Lau's answer does provide some of the info you need to resolve this, but the important part is that migrations don't inspect the database context at runtime, so you need to define the schema *before* you create your database migration.

Don't worry about extending `ConfigurationDbContext` either, as that's not needed, just add something like this to your `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    // ...
});

var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
identityServerBuilder.AddConfigurationStore(options =>
{
    options.DefaultSchema = "config";
    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
});
```

Once you've added that code, create a migration for the relevant database context:

```
Add-Migration CreateInitialSchema -Context ConfigurationDbContext
```

You should see that the created migration starts like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(
        name: "config");

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "ApiResources",
        schema: "config",
        columns: table => new ...
```

Comment: How is this different from the acceped answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Add-Migration -c ConfigurationContext` command does not startup your application and thus does not know how to resolve the classes in your constructor:

```cs
   public ConfigurationContext( //How do i resolve this, i dont know?
        DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, 
        ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions) 
        : base(options, storeOptions)
   { }
```

You need to add a parameterless constructor, as the error suggests:

```cs
public ConfigurationContext() 
    : base(/* todo default static logic here */)
{ /* and here */ }
```

### Why

The database migration tries to create an instance of the `ConfigurationContext` to determine the 'desired' state (the state you want your database to be after the database migration has been executed).

This migration is a static file inside your project saying which Columns and which indexes etc need to be added or removed to the database to create the 'desired' state.

This `Add-Migration` command simply reflects your code to find the right context, it does not go through your startup class to see which dependencies you have the find (this would become way to complex since there could also be runtime dependencies or dependencies based on App-settings, etc)